# Routing on Google Compute Engine from a machine that doesn't have public IP to the internet

Tags: google-compute-engine

On Google Compute Engine we have machines which do not have public IPs (because a quota limits the number of machines that can have public IP addresses).  We need these non-public-IP machines to access data from Google Storage buckets which appears to mean that we have to route to the Internet.  But we can't get to anything outside of our network from these non-public-IP machines.  All packets drop.

We've found some documentation https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#routing that describes setting up routing from machines that do not have public IP addresses to one that does.

We tried creating a machine "proxy" that has ip-forwarding turned on and has firewall rules that allow http and https (I don't think this detail matters, but we did it). We created a network "nat" that has a 0.0.0.0/0 forward to "proxy" rule.  Our hope was that data from the non-public-IP machine on the "nat" network would forward their packets to "proxy" and then "proxy" would act as a gateway to the Internet somehow, but this does not work.

I suspect that we have to do some kind of routing instruction on "proxy" that we aren't doing that tells proxy to forward to the Google Internet gateway, but I'm not sure what this should be. Perhaps a rule in iptables?  Or some sort of NAT program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use iptables NAT to get it working. On the proxy instance (as root):

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: It worked, I had to recreate the proxy, but after that it worked.  Thanks so much!