# Curl errors on remote but not on local

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, google-compute-engine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am attempting to run the following script on a virtual instance I have created on the google cloud:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

DS=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "7 days ago")
DE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "1 day ago")
account=123

## above specifies last weeks delivery

rm -f cookiejar

curl  /dev/null -s -S -L -f -c cookiejar 'https://url.io/auth/authenticate' -d name=usr -d passwd='pwd'
curl -o /dev/null -s -S -L -f -b cookiejar -c cookiejar 'https://adloox.io/auth/adminaccounts' -d account=$account

curl -s -S -L -f -o "report1.xlsx" -J -b cookiejar -c cookiejar "https://url.io/adquality/ajax-adblocking?categoryFw=&platform_id[]=7&id1=All&id2=&id3=All&id4=All&id5=&id11=&date=2019-12-09&date_start=$DS&date_end=$DE&website=&keywords=&zfTablePage=1&zfTableColumn=&zfTableOrder=desc&zfTableQuickSearch=&zfTableItemPerPage=100&zfTableDataTablesMaxRows=2628&zfTableItemPerPage=10000&zfTableExport=xlsx"

curl -s -S -L -f -o "report2.xlsx" -J -b cookiejar -c cookiejar "https://url.io/report/ajax-by-tag2?platform_id[]=7&id1=All&id2=&id3=All&id4=All&id5=&id11=&date=2019-12-09&date_start=$DS&date_end=$DE&website=&zfTablePage=1&zfTableColumn=&zfTableOrder=desc&zfTableQuickSearch=&zfTableItemPerPage=100&zfTableDataTablesMaxRows=10000&zfDetails=true&by_viewability=imps_sivt&device_id[]=all&tag_type_id[]=all&support_id[]=all&by_website=1&zfTableItemPerPage=10000&zfTableExport=xlsx"
```

### Set Up

- I have curl installed on my local desktop (running `windows 10` with `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS)
- I have curl installed on my remote (`google cloud virtual instance` set up with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`)
- Both have version `curl 7.58.0`

## Issue

When run on my local desktop there is no issue and the files download. When run on my remote I am able to log in however I receive the following error for the next curl line:

```
+ curl -o /dev/null -s -S -L -f -b cookiejar -c cookiejar https://url.io/auth/adminaccounts -d account=123
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Can someone confirm what else I should be looking at here? I would have thought if my `linux` and `curl` versions are the same, there wouldn't be an issue. Sorry if there are some other straight forward checks to do. This is my first time setting up a server.

Comment: Look at the servers logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

DS=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "7 days ago")
DE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "1 day ago")
account=123

## above specifies last weeks delivery

rm -f cookiejar

curl  /dev/null -s -S -L -f -c cookiejar 'https://url.io/auth/authenticate' -d name=usr -d passwd='pwd'
curl -o /dev/null -s -S -f -b cookiejar -c cookiejar 'https://adloox.io/auth/adminaccounts' -d account=$account

curl -s -S -L -f -o "report1.xlsx" -J -b cookiejar -c cookiejar "https://url.io/adquality/ajax-adblocking?categoryFw=&platform_id[]=7&id1=All&id2=&id3=All&id4=All&id5=&id11=&date=2019-12-09&date_start=$DS&date_end=$DE&website=&keywords=&zfTablePage=1&zfTableColumn=&zfTableOrder=desc&zfTableQuickSearch=&zfTableItemPerPage=100&zfTableDataTablesMaxRows=2628&zfTableItemPerPage=10000&zfTableExport=xlsx"

curl -s -S -L -f -o "report2.xlsx" -J -b cookiejar -c cookiejar "https://url.io/report/ajax-by-tag2?platform_id[]=7&id1=All&id2=&id3=All&id4=All&id5=&id11=&date=2019-12-09&date_start=$DS&date_end=$DE&website=&zfTablePage=1&zfTableColumn=&zfTableOrder=desc&zfTableQuickSearch=&zfTableItemPerPage=100&zfTableDataTablesMaxRows=10000&zfDetails=true&by_viewability=imps_sivt&device_id[]=all&tag_type_id[]=all&support_id[]=all&by_website=1&zfTableItemPerPage=10000&zfTableExport=xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your virtual instance does not have a public IP address, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848820/routing-on-google-compute-engine-from-a-machine-that-doesnt-have-public-ip-to-t?rq=1) might help you out.